# Why should I go for ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have added this question as to know the different views why people are using ASP.Net MVC.

I know that it is RESTful, could you please put in more details to help me. I have checked few blogs but no good answers.

I mean which drive me to get my ASP.Net website to ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: This is a far to open ended question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+use+asp.net+mvc

Comment: (Somewhat facetiously) A weekend at a spa would be restful too, but in that case it would be a good reason to go for it. In the case of MVC, not so much. It's all about using the right tool for the job, not using something because it ticks the boxes for buzzwords X, Y and Z :)

Comment: I have cast a delete vote on this question.

Answer (score 12):

There is loads of information on MVC out there, Have you checked out Scott Guthrie or Phil Haack's blogs. A simple google search will bring up loads of articles on pro's and con's. If you're not finding yourself interested in MVC then stick with webforms.

Comment: Ravia - he may not have downvoted you, but I did.  Israfel is right - your question is mostly out of laziness, and it shows that you've put very little thought into your decision.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the Nerd Dinner example?  Google "Nerd Dinner" and you'll find it.

Also, there is a bunch of information on REST out there.  All you need to do is type in REST into google and you'll see.

It'll take some reading, sure, but as a programmer you should be used to that.

It's a steep learning curve and a massive framework and there is simply no way to explain it all in a simple question / answer.

You'll need to play for a bit, and I suggest Nerd Dinner, and then maybe come back and ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to make a [W3C-WAI](http://www.w3.org/WAI/) complient website using webforms? It's hard. MVC give you much better control over your HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I just read your question again and wanted to add another answer as it is very different to my original.

I started using the framework because I was impressed with the lack of ViewState and a page life cycle that had to reconstruct all the controls again just to get values.

I was also impressed with it's speed and extensibility.

I love that I can overload everything and add my own flavour to it.  I love that I can write Views with no code behind.

I love that there is a very clear seperation of concerns and that it's very easy to maintain.

I like that's it's easy to write the code, get it working and then worry about the view.  I hate webforms where everything just seems tied together with no clear deliniation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

If you Google for

advantages of asp.net mvc

you'll find hundreds of blog articles on why ASP.NET MVC can be a good tool.  But none of that really helps YOU.  Here's my ultra-simple decision tree for choosing the best tool:

- **Choose MVC** if your team has a strong understanding of the web, are great developers, and/or have a background in other web frameworks besides ASP.NET.  MVC is ultra simple to use if you're used to something like Ruby on Rails or even vanilla ASP, but it's best for strong developers, not junior ones.
- **Choose Webforms** if your team is full of novice programmers and/or they have a strong background in webforms development.  This is also the best choice for intranet apps.